# Dell Power Edge r610 and iDRAC Express

Tags: dell

ON a Dell Power Edge R610 with integrated iDRAC Express, has anyone has real world problems accessing the iDRAC in the event of a system hang or crash of the operating system?  I need to know because i am considering using some systems with iDRAC Express for production but dont want to risk it if they cant be accessed remotely to be power cycled in the event the system hangs.

Answer (score 1):

I generally prefer the idrac enterprise as it has a dedicated ethernet port for management and remote media, but the express is fully accessible if configured properly even though it shares a nic. Just make sure if you are teaming the nics with your OS and switch, that the drac express is setup properly to account for that. I forget the exact setting, but Dell's documentation outlines it.

Comment: I also prefer iDrac Enterprise because iDrac Express does *not* have remote KVM